# Outside lights always on, but could there be a switch?

Tags: switch

We recently had our entire house rewired and are having some issues getting all complete.  One issue we are having is our outside lights were supposed to be switched near our back door.  The last electrician that was here told us they were “always on”.  I explained that they were supposed to be switched, but she said they were not.

The thing is there seems to be a box for a switch in the location we had planned.  The box has a hot black wire, and red, white, and copper wires.  Is there a chance that if this switch is wired up that it can cut power to the exterior lights?  Or is the fact that the exterior lights are currently on, with none of the wires in the box connected make it impossible for these to be switched?

Comment: you  are probably looking at wrong box for exterior lights.

Comment: "had our entire house rewired" implies there's an electrician who can either answer your question or fix their mistake. If they are incompetent, don't pay them for doing the job wrong and hire someone competent to correct it.

Comment: From a comment below, "The person who rewired the house seems to have lost the plan". Then you (or better yet a competent electrician) need to get the plans from the one who drew them up and have a good, thorough look over of them! The general contractor in charge of subbing out to the electrician needs to get involved and kick his sub-contracted employees in the hiney!

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance.  Unfortunately, the presence of wires does not mean much.  They would have to be exactly the same wires used by the lights.  The only way to determine that is to trace the circuit to find out where those wires go, or to ask the person who rewired the house to explain what happened or to correct the problem for you.

Comment: Thank You!  I think they are the right wires.  The person who rewired the house seems to have lost the plan at some point, and his people are just going through the motions, attaching fixtures.  Drywall is in and siding is on.  Since this is exactly how the layout was supposed to be, giving it a shot seems to be a reasonably safe bet, right?

Comment: @Joe I have no idea what that means.  The only data here is that there are some wires in a box.  Placing a switch between two unidentified wires is not necessarily going to work or even a good idea or safe.

Comment: This is something that someone on site is going to need to figure out. The wires that are going to the lights and the wires in the switch box need to be identified. It just takes someone there with the proper testing tools to put some attention on and figure out. There is nothing here that our conjecture is going to do to help on this one.

Comment: Are the red and black wires connected, if so disconnect them from each other and if the light goes off you know which two wires to put on the switch.

Comment: The red and black wires are not connected.  The wires in this box are on the same circuit as the outdoor lights.  Robert what data can I gather to help you help me?  Part of issue is the electrician shows up about once every 3 months at this point.  And the people that do don’t seem much more knowledgeable than me.  We are working with them through a terrible contractor that we are trying to cut ties with, but we’ve 90% of our electrical done and paid for already so if I can just figure out this issue it would go a long way to helping me move on from these guys.  Thank you!